# Passing a number as a string parameter

Tags: php

I have developed a ussd application in which i want users to pass a month and year as input e.g.

```
January 2014 should be = 012014

November 2014 should be = 112014
```

I have the following function:

```
function myfunt($monthyear){
    $str = sprintf("%02s", $monyear);
    echo $tr;
}
```

When i pass `012014` as a parameter it is converted to `5132`

Comment: if the string you pass in starts with 0, it means it's octal. Not really sure what it is you want to achieve thoudg, so hard to give any useful answer.

Comment: Btw, it would be nice if you could post the actual code you're using; it's obvious that this code will not output anything useful.

Comment: The code is supposed to get a persons details from the database.           list($month, $year) = explode("*", $monyear);                      $sql = select contribution from users where id="" and month=$month and year=$year;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are passing the parameter as myfunt(012014), but you will need to pass it as myfunt('012014'). Also, couple of minor typos in your code - $monyear should be $monthyear and echo $tr to be $str (Guess you already noticed them)

Comment: This has worked. But the input comes from the user's mobile phones and passed to to the php function i cannot add quotations. I wiil just restrict the users to put 1204 instead of 012014

Comment: What is the user actually inputting? I guess the string 012014 only right? I guess if you just pass this received variable to the function, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a soulution, using `substr` function extracting the year and the month from the  `$monthyear`argument.

```
function myfunt($monthyear){
    $monthNum = substr($monthyear, 0,2);
    $year = substr($monthyear, 2);
    $monthName = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthNum, 10));
    echo $monthName." ".$year; //out
}

myfunt("042014");
```

Result:

```
April 2014
```